# add_custom_command depending on another add_custom_command

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

We have two `add_custom_command` clauses, where one depends on the other:

1. The first command compiles an `.osl` source file into an `.oso` object file using the `oslc` compiler:

   ```
   set (oslc ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sandbox/bin/oslc)

   add_custom_command (
       OUTPUT "${oso_dir}/${oso_filename}"
       COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory "${oso_dir}"
       COMMAND "${oslc}" -I"${osl_include_path}" -o "${oso_dir}/${oso_filename}" "${osl_src_abs}"
       MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${osl_src_abs}
       DEPENDS ${${headers}} ${osl_src_abs} "${oslc}"
   )
   ```

   Notice the dependency on `${oslc}`: we explicitly depend on `${oslc}` because we need to make sure it exists before we can execute this command.
2. The second command "builds" (really, *deploys*) the `oslc` compiler by copying it from somewhere else:

   ```
   add_custom_command (
       OUTPUT "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sandbox/bin/oslc"
       COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${OSL_COMPILER} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sandbox/bin/
   )
   ```

**While this setup works, it has the side effect that both commands are *always* executed** (the second command followed by the first command) even when the `.osl` input file hasn't been modified.

It seems that this behavior is specific to Windows. It appears to work fine on Linux.

If the dependency to `${oslc}` is removed from the first command, the second command is no longer executed at all, even when the `oslc` compiler is missing; but on the other hand, `.osl` files are now only recompiled when they have changed since the last build, as desired (as long as `oslc` is present).

**Is there anything wrong with this setup?** If not, what is the right way to combine both features: compiling `.osl` files *only* when they have changed since the last build, and "building" the `oslc` compiler (required by the first step) when it doesn't yet exist?

The actual CMake script is available on GitHub:

- [Entire `CMakeLists.txt` file](https://github.com/appleseedhq/appleseed/blob/64746233b4fd2c2692150f30b204e015e68eb9d7/src/appleseed.shaders/CMakeLists.txt)
- [First `add_custom_command` clause](https://github.com/appleseedhq/appleseed/blob/64746233b4fd2c2692150f30b204e015e68eb9d7/src/appleseed.shaders/CMakeLists.txt#L209-L215)
- [Second `add_custom_command` clause](https://github.com/appleseedhq/appleseed/blob/64746233b4fd2c2692150f30b204e015e68eb9d7/src/appleseed.shaders/CMakeLists.txt#L263-L273)

Comment: I expect the second command to have a `DEPENDS`, too. It should depend on some output from the first command. You have to figure out, why the first command is always build. Why do you use MAIN_DEPENDENCY? Why has one argument of DEPENDS quotatiosmarks?

Comment: oslc is an executable, right? You should not depend on it, you should check it (FindOslc or similar) and then wrap the whole add_custom_command in a OSCL_FOUND.

Comment: @usr1234567 The second command has no `DEPENDS` because it doesn't depend on anything. It just needs to be run when the output (the `oslc` compiler) is missing. It is wrapped in quotes because the full path to `oslc` might contain spaces on Windows.

Comment: `It seems that this behavior is specific to Windows.` - Under *which generator* (Visual Studio, NMake) you have observed this behaviour? Just a guess: the build tool, corresponded to this generator, doesn't understand commands without dependencies and treats them like a CMake *target* (which is always built). Adding `DEPENDS ${OSL_COMPILER}` into the second command should help with that. (Instead of `${OSL_COMPILER}` may be any source file which is never modified).

Comment: @Tsyvarev This behavior is observed with the `Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64` generator. I'll try your suggestion and report back here. Thanks!

Comment: @Tsyvarev Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried quoting the paths properly (e.g. `"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sandbox/bin/oslc"`)?

Comment: @sakra Yes, I've tried that. I think that this question is similar to mine, and the conclusion is basically that what I'm trying to achieve isn't possible with CMake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution, at least for Windows, is to change the second command to

```
add_custom_command (
    TARGET appleseed.shaders
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${OSL_COMPILER} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sandbox/bin/
)
```

(notice the `PRE_BUILD` keyword)

and to remove the explicit dependency to `${oslc}` from the first command.